# What's the error within this code?

Tags: c++

When I try to build this code it shows errors!
and I don't know how to solve it!!

**error C3531: 'x': a symbol whose type contains 'auto' must have an initializer

error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':'**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

   int main(){
ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");
string s;
int line=0;
vector<string> vec(1,"dummy");
multimap<int,int> M;

while(getline(in, s)){
    line++;
    vec.push_back(s);
    if(line%12==10){
        string temp="";
        for(auto x:s) if(isdigit(x)) temp+=x;
        int key = stoi(temp);
        M.insert(make_pair(key,line));      
    }
}

auto it = M.rbegin();
while(it != M.rend()){      
    int i = it->second;
    int start = (int(i/12))*12 +1;
    for(int j=1; j<=12; j++) out << vec.at(start++) << "\n";        
    it++;
}


in.close();
out.close();    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using? Looks like it's one that doesn't support range based `for`.

Comment: It's 2010?!!
so how i can solve it?!

Comment: Upgrade to VS2012 or later. Or stop using range based `for` loops

Comment: @Kurd No the current year is 2015

Comment: as Praetorian said, range based for loops only implemented in VS2012 & later. If you do not have to use VS, g++ ( version >= 4.7) supports them.

Comment: @Praetorian: VS2013 I thought

Comment: @Lightness It was VS2012, look towards the end of [this table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable). I remember this one because people were pissed about how few C++11 features were being included when they first announced VS2012, so they scrambled and added ranged for in after the initial announcement. But, of course, if OP has the option, he should upgrade to the latest available.

Comment: @Praetorian: Yep okie dokie

Comment: (It must have been the init lists I was thinking of)

Answer (score 1):

The MS VC++ 2010 does not support standard syntax for the range based for loop. But it supports the following syntax:

```
for each (auto x in s) if(isdigit(x)) temp+=x;
```

Thus this is the reason for the compilation errors.

Comment: _+1:_ Silly Microsoft ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Since VS2010 doesn't support the syntax, just use the pre-c++11 syntax:

```
if(line%12==10){
    string temp="";
    for (std::string::const_iterator iter=s.begin(); iter!=s.end(); ++iter)
        if (isdigit(*iter)) temp += *iter;
    int key = stoi(temp);
    M.insert(make_pair(key,line));      
}
```

or maybe:

```
if (line%12 == 10) {
    int key = 0;
    for (std::string::const_iterator iter=s.begin(); iter!=s.end(); ++iter)
        if (isdigit(*iter)) key = (key * 10) + (*iter - '0');
    M.insert(make_pair(key, line));
}
```

and get rid of the temporary string and `stoi`